# Angular material Paginator is not working

Tags: angular, pagination, angular5, angular-material2, angular-material-paginator

I am trying to add Angular Material Paginator on my app.

**MatPaginatorModule** added in module.

```
<mat-paginator #paginator 
               [length]="100" 
               [pageSize]="10" 
               [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

But It gives a Error:

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:

> Can't bind to 'length' since it isn't a known property of
>   'mat-paginator'.

1. If `mat-paginator` is an Angular component and it has `length` input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If `mat-paginator` is a Web Component then add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to the `@NgModule.schemas` of this component to suppress this message.

Maybe i am missing something?

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
```

Answer (score 106):

Just in case someone else runs into this problem, all it takes is importing the module in app.module.ts

```
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
```

and

```
@NgModule({
...
imports: [ 
....
MatPaginatorModule ]
```

Comment: PERFECT!!! Never realized this had to be done manually even after importing the MatTableModule! Thanks for your solution. BTW, this is the (updated?) syntax for importing the Paginator module: `import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';`

Comment: thanks, urhg the documentation for angular material and bootstrap needs some serious polishing.

Answer (score 29):

I have noticed one thing which I think I should mention, It maybe useful or not. 
If you are using Angular Materials version 5 the paginator module is present in

```
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material';
```

But from Angular 8 onwards its present in

```
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
```

Be sure to add the module in app.module.ts too

Answer (score 4):

```
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it also required `MatChipsModule` to compile.

```
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this issue last day and I found the solution as adding necessary records to the **project.module.ts** file. I think you should do something like this.

```
import { NameOfYourComponent } from './path_to_your_component/nameofyour.component';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NameOfYourComponent ,
...
```